# database schema of "don't show me again what I saw before" in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-schema

I'm making a website that shows you images. And special feature of site is "don't show me again what I saw before". It means, if you see a image, it goes to your "archive" category. There will be so many images and categories. And I need to very smooth schema of database to perfomance.

When you click a image, it appears on lightbox and in the lightbox code it sends request with ajax to make this image archived just for you.

Is that database schema above performanceful for about 5.000 images and 20.000 users?

```
users
  user_id
  user_email

pictures
  picture_id
  picture_url
  tags

archived
  user_id
  picture_id
```

images will appear on front of you with excepting archived images for you from all images on this schema...

Comment: @Yoshi not 100k it'll 100M.. 5.000 row for each user.

Comment: Ah of course! Should think more before babbling! ;)

Comment: Best way would be not to save the viewed ones - but to keep track of unseen ones. This way you don't increase the amount of data as user browses images and you are able to set everything as "viewed", simply by removing "new image" entries.

Comment: Not what you may want to hear but... you could use a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "NOT IN" solution for a while and there is performance problems started. Because I don't have a strong server to execute that query with lot of datas.

So, I found the most performanceful answer : "Collection Shuffle"

> I'm shuffleing the collection with a userid seed and saving just users last image index id. After user comes back, looking to where this user's index id left lastly, showing next id from his collection.

This is really light and exactly solution. Thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a diificult question to answer without knowing all the details.  You mention how many users and images there will be.  How many images will each user (on average) have in their archived list?  If that number is small, the archived table won't approach 100M rows.

100M rows should not be a problem by itself, as the database can handle this.  The concern may (or will) be with the way you are going to want to query the data.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  picture
WHERE 
  picture_id NOT IN 
  (
     SELECT picture_id FROM archived WHERE user_id = [userIdParameter]
  )
```

That will likely not perform very well with 100M rows.

Another option would be to cross join users and pictures so that the archived table always contains a Cartesian product.  So the table would be:

```
archived
  user_id
  picture_id
  visited
```

Then you could query like so:

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  picture p
  INNER JOIN archived a ON p.picture_id = a.picture_id
WHERE 
  a.user_id = [userIdParameter]
  AND a.visited = [false]
```

This should perform acceptably with proper indexing, but would present the problem of having to make sure rows are created in the archived table any time a user or picture is added to the system.  It also means you would *always* have a number of rows equal to pictures * users (100M in your example).  That may not be desirable in your case.

Bottom line, you are going to have to create some test data that approximates your expected volume and do some performance testing that approximates your load.  If you think this is the critical potential performance bottleneck for your system, it will be worth the time investment.

Comment: Doing a `LEFT JOIN` and adding a `a.id IS NULL` condition should make the a.visited field unnecessary, and perform well. I edited your answer to take that into account, rollback if you disagree.

Comment: or edit further if you agree, there are still references to "visited" in your post, and the first query is perhaps irrelevant now.

Comment: My first query is effectively what you edited my second query to be (NOT IN vs. "reverse inner join"). And, whether it's a good idea or not, you absolutely missed the point the second query and the concept of a cartesian product. If you are going to have the *blatant audacity* to edit the content of someone's answer, at least make sure you understand the answer first. Rolled back.

Comment: "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." says the faq. I couldn't guess you would type your answer then run away, could I? I was not entirely sure I got your second point, but I thought you would quickly edit your answer to make it correct again, and not make a fuss of it, but obviously, I was wrong. Very sorry.

Comment: Are you going to take my remark into account (but in your first query) or are you too angry for that? The join would surely perform far far better than a NOT IN. And maybe you could explain why a table with a cartesian product is better (if it is, I don't know).

Comment: I'm not angry and I am not looking for drama or an argument. But your apology is about the most insincere and condescending one I have ever heard. LEFT JOIN with IS NULL is one way to do a "reverse inner join" or anti-join. NOT IN is another, and NOT EXISTS is yet another. They are all functionally the same and the best one to use is not always obvious. Read: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/.

Comment: The Cartesian product idea was just that--an idea. It was something I instinctively thought might perform better. My thinking was that it might be able to take better advantage of indexes on the (very large) archive table, where an anti-join might cause a bottleneck.

Comment: (sincere) thanks for your answers and for the link, it's interesting

Comment: @PhilSandler as the post owner it is your right to roll back any edits you feel don't further the purpose of your post. The only problem is if there is an edit/rollback war but that doesn't seem to be the case here...